# Create cron in chef

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I want to create Cron in chef witch they verify size of the log if it's > 30mb it will delete it, here is my code:

```
cron_d 'ganglia_tomcat_thread_max' do
    hour '0'
  minute '1'
  command "rm - f /srv/node/current/app/log/simplesamlphp.log"
  only_if { ::File.size('/srv/node/current/app/log/simplesamlphp.log').to_f / 1024000 > 30 }
end
```

Can you help me in it please

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stackoverflow!

I suggest you to go with existing tools like "logrotate". [There is a chef cookbook available to manage logrotate](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/logrotate).

Please note, that "cron" in chef manages the system cron service which runs independently of chef. You'll have to do the file size check within the "command". It's also better to use the `cron_d` resource [as documented here](https://docs.chef.io/resource_cron_d.html).

Comment: can you help me please to create this ?

Answer (score 1):

In the way you create `cron_d` resource it will add cron task only when your log file has size greater than 30mb. In all other cases `cron_d` will be not created.

You can check that ruby code

```rb
File.size('file').to_f / 2**20
```

to get the file size in Megabytes - there is a slight difference in the result I believe that is more correct.

so you can go wirh 2 solutions for your specific case

- create new `cron_d` resource when log file is less than 30 mb to remove existing cron and provision your node periodically
- move the check of the file size in the command with bash and glue with && - in that case file will be dated only if size is greater than 30mb. something like that

```sh
du -k file.txt | cut -f1
```

will return size of the file in bytes

To me also correct way to to that is to use logrotate service and chef recipe for that.